# Register in first step of checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, register

I want that on a custom checkout page to have as a first step select checkout: login, register and checkout as guest. I have managed to login customer and then to remain on checkout page. When the user chose register radio button, I need to display the register form and to register the user and then to continue checkout process with the logged in customer.
I am stuck with register form, so maybe you have an idea.
[image]

Comment: May I ask why you want to register the customer on the first step? Sure it is possible but it could feel like a lot of work for what can be done by Magento just slightly differently with registration after checkout is complete.